# IE7 sibling div width not same as sibling

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-7

I am struggling with fixing an IE7 issue.  I want my sibling div to be the same width as it's siblings.  The first sibling acts as the header while the other siblings have certain dimensions.  I could use some advice.

http://jsbin.com/etuxum/19/edit

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason that everything is floating?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
.rateSection {
float: left;
margin-right: 0px;
width: 100%;
}
```

Notice margin-right: 0px;
The blue background is aplied to the

if you add `background-color:#999;` to `.rateSection` you get what you want

Comment: Thanks but in IE7 I still can't get the blue heading to be the same width as both red boxes.

Comment: But the blue background is aplied to the <p> if you add `background-color:#999;` to `.rateSection` you get what you want or?

Comment: Nice! Added that on my answer so it's more complete.